# Flutter TypeAheadFormField

Tags: flutter

I just want to use the TypeAhead for suggestions. But if the user doesn't select a suggested one the field should use the typed... It still stays with the initial value.

Somehow I'm stuck how to code

```
child: FormBuilderTypeAhead<String>(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: hint,
      labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 12),
      focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: appColor),
      ),
      enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12),
      ),
    ),
      name: name,
      onChanged: onChanged,
      itemBuilder: (context, country) {
        return ListTile(title: Text(country));
      },
      controller: typeAheadController,
      initialValue: initial,
      suggestionsCallback: (query) {

        if (query.isNotEmpty) {
          var lowercaseQuery = query.toLowerCase();
          return allCountries.where((country) {
            return country.toLowerCase().contains(lowercaseQuery);
          }).toList(growable: false)
            ..sort((a, b) => a
                .toLowerCase()
                .indexOf(lowercaseQuery)
                .compareTo(
                b.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowercaseQuery)));
        } else {
          return allCountries;
        }
      },

    )
```